# How to join characters in an array into a string?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I'm trying to transform a text into a Spongebob mocking style text, like this:

> Hello World! = hElLo WoRlD.

I split the string into an array and converted the letters, but I cant only print them as an array.

How do I join the characters into a string?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Word As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Letters() As String

Word = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

Letters = Split(StrConv(Word, 64), Chr(0))
For i = 0 To Len(Word) - 1 Step 2
    Debug.Print StrConv(Letters(i), 1)
    Debug.Print StrConv(Letters(i + 1), 2)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try using [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)?

Comment: Or using a temp string variable and concatenating each character to the temp string in the loop?

Comment: @BigBen I used this after next i
`Result = Join(lower, "")
Debug.Print Result`
after declaring lower as an array but it didnt work

Comment: @ScottCraner How do I do it?

Comment: `temp = temp & StrConv(Letters(i), 1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner This works thank you, I had to add `& StrConv(Letters(i+1), 1)` after your code, to add both odd characters and even characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) to concatenate the array of characters. You can modify the contents of `Letters` directly to get the lower-case/upper-case alternation, something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Word As String
    Word = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    Dim Letters() As String
    Letters = Split(StrConv(Word, 64), Chr(0))

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Letters) To UBound(Letters)
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Letters(i) = StrConv(Letters(i), 2) '<~ or `LCase$`
        Else
            Letters(i) = StrConv(Letters(i), 1) '<~ or `UCase$`
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print Join(Letters, "")
End Sub
```

Comment: This is way better than the idea I was going for. it works! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

For your code all you need to do is create a new variable to hold your newly created string.

```
DIM allLetters As String
```

Then join the `Letters()` using the `Join()` method.

```
allLetters = Join(Letters)
```

Here's the documentation on joining.

https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-join-function.html

```
' Join together the strings "John", "Paul" and "Smith".
Dim fullName As String
Dim names( 0 to 2 ) As String
names(0) = "John"
names(1) = "Paul"
names(2) = "Smith"
fullName = Join( names )
' The variable fullName is now set to "John Paul Smith"
```

## Reference

VBA JOIN Function. (n.d.). Retrieved from https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-join-function.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't know how to properly use the join method.
@BigBen gave me how and where to add it to the script. Now it works!